# what is the fastest way to find the same geopoint in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, window-functions

i have a table with 80 000 000 rows which are geopoints from 20 000 different gid.

my table has this form :

| gid | idx_pt | id_unique | x | y | geom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | na | 65250.78 | 700000.52 | 01010000206A..... |
| 1 | 2 | na | 65250.78 | 700000.52 | 01010000206A..... |
| 1 | 3 | na | 65250.78 | 700000.52 | 01010000206A..... |
| 1 | 4 | na | 65999.00 | 700555.00 | 01010000455A..... |
| 1 | 5 | na | 65999.00 | 700555.00 | 01010000455A..... |
| 1 | 6 | na | 65999.00 | 700555.00 | 01010000455A..... |

for each gid i have like thousands of gepoints (ex gid 1 ==> 5097 rows).

Some of the geopoints are the same (like the three first points in my example above) and i want for each idx_pt to find the first geopoint of the gid
When identified i need to update the id_unique columns with the idx_pt of the first point found.

what i am looking for :

| gid | idx_pt | id_unique | x | y | geom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 65250.78 | 700000.52 | 01010000206A..... |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 65250.78 | 700000.52 | 01010000206A..... |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 65250.78 | 700000.52 | 01010000206A..... |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 65999.00 | 700555.00 | 01010000455A..... |
| 1 | 5 | 4 | 65999.00 | 700555.00 | 01010000455A..... |
| 1 | 6 | 4 | 65999.00 | 700555.00 | 01010000455A..... |

I succeed to perform this update but i have a problem of performance.
I run my postgresql server on a small server (nas synology) and the query is running for more than 24 hours now and just 50% of the query is done ...
to be sure that even if the server closed prematurally i keep the update rows i do a for loop update with a commit instruction for each gid.

my query for gid = 1 :

```
SELECT a.idx_pt as idx_pt, c.idx_pt as id_unique
FROM mytable a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
SELECT  idx_pt as idx_pt
FROM mytable 
WHERE
gid = a.gid
AND
ST_Equals(a.geom , geom)
ORDER BY idx_pt
LIMIT 1
) c 
WHERE a.gid = 1
```

The logic is : for each idx_pt i do a lateral join based on the same gid, same geopoints ordered by the idx_pt column and keeping only the first rows.

this query take 12 seconds to perform on my little server (5097 rows X 5097 rows)

My problem is than i have 20 000 gid for a total of 80 000 000 rows so it is very very slow.

My Question : how could i improve the performance for this task ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your statements and also share the DDL for the tables? Including the indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window function `FIRST_VALUE()` with a `PARTITION` by `gid, geom` is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
  gid,idx_pt,
  FIRST_VALUE(idx_pt) OVER w AS id_unique,
  x,y,geom
FROM mytable
WHERE gid = 1
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY gid,geom ORDER BY idx_pt
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY gid, idx_pt;
```

A `CROSS JOIN` means that for each record you would fire a full scan in your 80m records table, which is highly inefficient.

The frame `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` is optional in this case, but it is considered to be a good practice to make things explicit. It basically tells the function to perform its operations in the given partition considering all records from it, as `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` means every record *before* the current row and `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` means every record *after* the current row. Window functions are not very palatable at first, but once you get the gist of it they become your best friends.

Regarding speed: make sure the column `gid` is properly indexed.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f8d69c6accd473b6389a95c9a50a9987)

**Side note**: to store the longitude and latitude values alongside a geometry column containing the same coordinates is not really necessary. You can always get the x and y values from the geometries using `ST_X` and `ST_Y`, respectively. In a 80m rows table this would make some difference in disk usage ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! from 12 sec to 135 ms !!

About the x and y value stored thanks for the tips but i have to store them because i later use it outside postgis/postgre... it is the geom col that i don't need at the end (but i keep it for postgis queries)

Again thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please explain a bit your window function ? particulary the 'RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING' part ?