# How to query all the FIRST_VALUE in a window function to then find the ROW_NUMBER of each FIRST_VALUE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

My question follow a previous question : [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73526563/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-same-geopoint-in-a-table)

Thanks for the help on StackOverflow i am now able to use a window function to find the unique_id (= when a geopoint is repeated i only keep the idx_pt first time he appears)

But now i am struggling with the id_unique_ordered column : the idx_pt 6 is the first time the geopoint appears but it is also the 4th unique geopoint that appears.

i tried the following [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0fe8e741d2a50c901a18ab7dd4bf89d2) and **it works** but it use a join and i'm not sur it is the best way to do it and i'm concerned with performance as i have a lot of point in my table (80M).

| gid | idx_pt | id_unique | id_unique_ordered | geom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0A01... |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0B01... |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 0C01... |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0A01... |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 0B01... |
| 1 | 6 | 6 | **4** | 0D01... |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 0A01... |
| 1 | 8 | 2 | 2 | 0B01... |
| 1 | 9 | 9 | **5** | 0E01... |

The code look like this  :

```
        WITH sub_query AS (
    SELECT

    gid,
    idx_pt,
    id_unique,
    CASE WHEN idx_pt = id_unique THEN True ELSE False END AS unique_bool,
    geom

    FROM
    (SELECT 
      gid,idx_pt,
      FIRST_VALUE(idx_pt) OVER w AS id_unique,
      x,y,geom
    FROM mytable
    WHERE gid = 1
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY gid,geom ORDER BY idx_pt
                 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    ORDER BY gid,idx_pt) as sub_bool
    )  


    SELECT

    gid,
    idx_pt,
    sub_query.id_unique as id_unique,
    t2.row_num as id_unique_ordered,
    unique_bool,
    geom

    FROM sub_query
    LEFT JOIN (select ROW_NUMBER() over () as row_num, id_unique FROM sub_query where unique_bool = True order by id_unique) as t2
    ON sub_query.id_unique = t2.id_unique
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with create table, insert statements like in my previous answer? Otherwise it is difficult to reproduce your example.

Comment: Also add the whole query you've tried so far, not only the window function call.

Comment: Hello Jim, i added a fiddle and edit the post. thanks for your help !
I use a join to succeed but i feel there is a more elegant and optimized way to do it.

Comment: Can you tell me if this is what you're looking for? (last query):
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=49c67c737c31219273d0c3618bccd02b I believe it can be further reduced to a single query, but before we dive into optimization it is best first to be sure if this works

Comment: yes that it ! i focus to the best way on how retrieve the bool column and how retrieve the id_unique_ordered column
But that's it is the last query that i want to optimize

if idx_pt = id_unique then True else False

and if the first geopoint found for a given idx_pt is the Xth geopoint found for the given gid i want to get this value (Xth)